# Proof by induction summation inequality: $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = O(n^3)$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, asymptotics

show by induction that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2  = O(n^3)$$

what I have so far:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \le n^3$$

base case: for n=1
$$\sum_{i=1}^1 i^2 \le 1^3$$
--------------------------------------------------> 1=1 is correct

inductive step: assume true for n=k then for n=k+1

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^2 + (k+1)^2 \le k^3 + (k+1)^2$$

$$\le k^3 +(k+1)^2 \le k^3 +(k+1)^2$$

$$...$$
at this point I am not sure where to go to finish off this proof can someone advise?

**EDIT**
solution:
$$k^3 + (k+1)^2 = k^3 + k^2 +2k + 1$$
$$(k+1)^3 = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^2 \le k^3 + k^2 + 2k +1 <= k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$ 
$$ therefore \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^2 \le (k+1)^3$$
------------------------------------------->statement is true for n=k+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done!
$$k^3+(k+1)^2=k^3+k^2+2k+1\le k^3+3k^2+3k+1=(k+1)^3$$

Comment: Thanks! So basically the proof is saying that the LHS is <= k^3 + (k+1)^2 and since (k+1)^3 is greater than k^3 +(k+1)^2 it is implied that the LHS is also <= (k+1)^3. Correct?

Comment: @Animorv Yes, that's called the transitivity of $\le$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tedious approach.

Suppose, by analogy with integration, that
$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = a n^3 + b n^2 + c n + d$, then we can  solve for $a,b,c,d$ by getting 4 equations in $(a,b,c,d)$ by setting $n=1,2,3,4$. This gives
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27 \\
1 & 4 & 16 & 64 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d \\ c \\ b \\ a\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 14 \\ 30\end{bmatrix} $, and solving
gives $(a,b,c,d) = ({1 \over 3}, {1 \over 2}, {1 \over 6}, 0)$.

Now we need use induction to check that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = 
s_2(n) = {1 \over 3}n^3 +{1 \over 2} n^2+ {1 \over 6}n$. It is true for $n=1$, so suppose it is true for $n$, then
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 = {1 \over 3}n^3 +{1 \over 2} n^2+ {1 \over 6}n + (n+1)^2 = {1 \over 3}n^3 +{3 \over 2} n^2+ {13 \over 6}n +1$,
computing $s_2(n+1)$ directly gives the same result, hence the result is
true of all $n$.

Comment: How do you solve for $(a,b,c,d)$ here?

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons: It is invertible since it is a Vandermonde matrix, the solution can be found by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Ok, what is a vandermonde matrix and what is gaussian elimination?

Comment: A Vandermonde matrix has a particular form that allows one to see that it is invertible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Properties). Gaussian elimination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is a technique for solving systems of equations of the form $Ax=b$.

Comment: One can solve the four equations using the usual algebra method of multiplying and adding rows (which is what Gaussian elimination amounts to, albeit more formally).